# Problemas para centrar un texto en una columna en un container en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, app

estoy haciendo una app por aburrimiento y me surgido un problema que lleva dos días tocándome la moral, la cosa es que quiero hacer una lista infinita en la que se vea una foto, un par de iconos y dos textos, para ello he creado, dentro de un ListView.builder, un center que devuelve un container, que retorna una columna y que a su vez devuelve un Row con texto e icono, una foto y un segundo Row con dos textos, todo esto a modo de prueba, sin embargo todo se me queda en el margen izquierdo de la columna y el container ¿Alguna pista de por qué pasa estoy como lo puedo solucionar? Muchas gracias de antemano

Adjunto código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePageUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageUser({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePageUser> createState() => _HomePageUserState();
}

class _HomePageUserState extends State<HomePageUser> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        //itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Center(
            child: Container (
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            alignment:Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                  spreadRadius: 2.0,
                  offset: const Offset(
                    5.0,
                    5.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text('Nombre'),),
                        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10), child: Icon(Icons.open_in_new),),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text('Estrellas'),
                        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),),
                        Text('(rango)')
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: como desees que se vea? dices que te queda todo a un lado izquierdo pero no dices como debe mostrarlo

Answer (score 1):

Para que el contenido se vea al centro, puedes usar el `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` en tus `Row`s.

Queda así:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      //itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                blurRadius: 10.0,
                spreadRadius: 2.0,
                offset: Offset(
                  5.0,
                  5.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text('Nombre'),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: Icon(Icons.open_in_new),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Text('Estrellas'),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  ),
                  Text('(rango)')
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha arreglado el problema

Comment: si la respuesta de @diegoveloper te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada, para que así puedas ayudar a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema que tu.